# Is there software that draws geometric figures and prints to scale?

Tags: geometry, math-software

What software can I use to make geometric drawings like this?
[image]

I tried GeoGebra but it doesn't print in scale.

Comment: Mathcad or Geometer's Sketchpad should work well but you have to purchase a license to use them. But there are free (similar) versions on the web which you can use to construct the images: https://www.geogebra.org/ (try GeoGebra Geometry).

Comment: I use inkscape to make drawings like this. It is a general purpose open source vector graphics program, not math specific.

Comment: On-scale printing is sometimes only achievable by embedding your image into a document that allows you to give the scale you desire. It can be a Word document. Sometimes, I incorporate my images into a latex document and scale them with a ratio that I know to give a reliable result on my printer/

Comment: Have you tried to export images from GeoGebra? In the dialog box you can give a scale factor.